# Open a file from physical path from web

Tags: c#, asp.net

`string ImageFilePath = "c:\picture\test.jpg";
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
procInfo.FileName = ("mspaint.exe");
procInfo.Arguments = ImageFilePath;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procInfo);`

This code is working in development time, when I deploy it in web, it not working? please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Usually you can't run your code against client computers over the web.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using relative path and picture should be in deployment folder (where application is hosted).

Second, did user has permission on C:\Picture?